# Start with empty dtPicker Value, then change format after pressing sumbit button

Tags: vba, excel, datetimepicker

I've really struggled with this one, I've browsed through Google but not found a working solution for me. This is the case (using US Office 2016 and added the mscomct2.ocx);

Loading the Excel also loads UserForm1.
Within this, I have a 'DateFrom' and 'DateTo' using the DateTimePicker.

At startup I would like both to show empty (using checkbox is not an option). After choosing the appropriate 'DateFrom' and 'DateTo' the presented format in the UserForm is .dtpLongDate (set from the dtPicker properties box).

When pressing the submit button, I need the DateTimePicker format to change from .dtpLongDate to Custom format "yyyy-MM-dd" so I can put the DateFrom.Value into a string which needs this specific format.

I've tried everything I've found, but as I'm quite novice on VB, nothing I've tried seem to work.

This is the code I have in the start of the command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim TerminalIDRange As Range
Dim ii As Long
Set FormlerSheet = Worksheets("Formler")
Set DataSheet = Worksheets("Data")
Set TerminalIDRange = DataSheet.Range("M2:M2000")

DateFrom.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateTo.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateFrom.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
DateTo.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

MsgBox DateFrom.Value
```

Still the DateFrom.Value show me date as dd.mm.yyyy for some reason.

Also; to set code for the DateFrom and DateTo to be blank after loading the UserForm, where do I place this code??

Hope somebody can help me on this...

Comment: I don't think you can initialize a DatePicker with blank value (value 0 is still a date). You may want to put a textbox below the DatePicker, have the picker not visible during form initialize, then perhaps a click/dblclick on the textbox to make the picker visible, then set the textbox to the date user clicked.

Comment: Okie, can you please provide some sample code in how to do this? Seems like a good solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understand you right, you just need the date in the form `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.
Then you could also just read `DateFrom.Value` and convert it with `Format$`, like this:

```
Dim s as string
s = Format$(DateFrom.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")
MsgBox s
```

Comment: This sorted the Format issue :)
Still, I do not have the solution on how to set the default value as "empty" (no date chosen) after the UserForm has loaded.